# perl retry on fail for eval

Tags: perl, eval

I'm trying to retry an action on fail, I have a working code but I think there is a way more elegant way to do that:

```
    eval {
        my $stuff1 = function1();
        my $stuff2 = function2();
    };
    if ($@) {
        print 'ERROR: '
            . ( $@ ? "$@\n" : "Wrong.\n" );  
    }
    else {
            function3();
    }
    function4();
```

So I've modified it into this:

```
    my $check = -1;
    eval {
        my $stuff1 = function1();
        my $stuff2 = function2();
    }
    if ($@) {
        for (my $num_tries = 3; ; ) {
            last if eval {
                print "Failed\n";
                sleep(2);
                my $stuff1 = function1();
                my $stuff2 = function2();
                return $check = 1;
            };     
        }
        print 'ERROR: '
            . ( $@ ? "$@\n" : "Wrong.\n" );
    }
    if ($check == 1) {
            function3();
    } 
    function4();
```

So I was wondering if there's something "cleaner" to write than that? To try not reusing the 2 same functions 2 times, but just once?

```
my $check = -1;
for (my $num_tries = 3; ; ) {
    last if eval {
        my $stuff1 = function1();
        my $stuff2 = function2();
        return $check = 1;  # No exception.
    };

    --$num_tries;

    chomp( my $e = $@ );
    warn("$e Retrying...");
    if ($num_tries == 3) {
        print 'ERROR: '
        . ( $@ ? "$@\n" : "Wrong.\n" );
    }
}
if ($check == 1) {
        function3();
}
function4();
```

EDIT: modified the 2nd part

Answer (score 4):

Your solution doesn't even work because the second set of calls isn't in an `eval`. Fixed:

```
for (my $num_tries = 3; ; ) {
    last if eval {
        my $stuff1 = function1();
        my $stuff2 = function2();
        function3();
        return 1;  # No exception.
    };

    --$num_tries
        or die($@);

    chomp( my $e = $@ );
    warn("$e Retrying...");
}

function4();
```

---

The above moved `function3();` into the `eval`. If you want to allow it to throw an exception (or maybe it's really a `return`, `last`, etc), you can use the following instead:

```
my $num_tries = 3;
while (1)
    last if eval {
        my $stuff1 = function1();
        my $stuff2 = function2();
        return 1;  # No exception.
    } || !--$num_tries;

    chomp( my $e = $@ );
    warn("$e Retrying...");
}

if ($num_tries) {
    function3();
} else {
    warn($@);
}

function4();
```

This is getting a bit complicated again, so let's use a sub!

```
sub non_fatal_retry(&$) {
    my ($cb, $num_tries) = @_

    while (!eval { $cb->(); 1 }) {
        --$num_tries
            or warn($@), return 0;

        chomp( my $e = $@ );
        warn("$e Retrying...");
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The solution becomes:

```
if (non_fatal_retry {
    my $stuff1 = function1();
    my $stuff2 = function2();
}, 3) {
    function3();
}

function4();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't wanna die if it fails here, because I have code that need to be executed after. How do I "only" go in the else if there's no error and continue if there is with the retries?

Comment: So use `eval` to catch it, or use `last` plus a flag. You could even use `$num_retries` as the flag by moving its declaration.

Comment: Ok I modified my code, would this work? I'm not sure how to use what you just told me, thanks!

Comment: That would work (though you really should use `0` and `1`, a false and a true value). But you again introduced needless complexity and a couple of problems (print a retry error message even when you won't; printing error messages to STDOUT). See my updated answer

Comment: Hi ikegami, thanks the code you wrote worked. I couldn't use the function tho because this small piece of code is a part of a bigger code and it would have been a lot of argument to pass. Just one question, how does !--$num_tries; works? It exit when it hits 0?

Comment: What are you taking about? You should be using `non_fatal_retry` as is. You should not be passing any arguments to it I didn't pass

Comment: If `$num_tries` is initially 1, it will become zero and false, and thus `warn` and `return` will be evaluated.

Comment: Oh ok I see.. "warn" didn't print the statement in the log tho. If I use "print", will it still works? Thank you so much!

Comment: That would seem to indicate you redirected STDOUT to a file, but didn't redirect STDERR to it too. In other words, `>log` should be `>log 2>&1`. Don't compound your error by replacing `warn` with `print.` Error messages are sent to STDERR. You're already missing out on warnings, for example.